# Day number date formatting keeps counting past the end of the month

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, formatting, nsdateformatter

I have a tableview with sections separated by days as follows:

Jan 15, 2012
Jan 16, 2012
Jan 21, 2012
Jan 30, 2012
Jan 31, 2012
Feb 1, 2012
Feb 2, 2012

I am using the following code:

```
UILabel * lbDayOfWeek = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
NSDate * date = [m_arEventsSorted objectAtIndex:section];
NSDateFormatter* theDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[theDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString * weekDay =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
lbDayOfWeek.text = weekDay;

UILabel * lbMonthDayYear = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
[theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM D YYYY"];
NSString * monthDayYear =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
lbMonthDayYear.text = monthDayYear;
```

But my days do not start over at the end of the month.  For example, I get the following:

Jan 15, 2012
Jan 16, 2012
Jan 21, 2012
Jan 30, 2012
Jan 31, 2012
Feb 32, 2012
Feb 33, 2012

I am not sure why the above code is outputting the wrong days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [formatting specifiers](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). A capital 'D' means day of *year*, when you want day of *month*. The first day of February is also the 32nd day of the year.

Your format string should be `@"MMM d yyyy"`.

(Also watch out for the distinction between lowercase and uppercase 'y'. You almost always want lowercase -- see note #1 under ["Date Formatting: Fixed Formats"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13) in the Data Formatting Guide.)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for NSDateFormatterMediumStyle, don't set the format, set the style instead of the format:

```
[theDateFormatter setDateFormat: NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

The date format should be used only when you don't find a style that matches your needs. In this case the format would be `@"MMM d, yyyy"` .